# Please explain about proc command in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am a new learner in Tcl. Please explain it....

what is the work of [proc]  command in Tcl ?  I know that [proc] build  a new command but want to understand it more closely.

Comment: Please have a look at the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm)

Comment: @GMZ, Your question is too broad, with little research in google you can gain the knowledge about your topic.

Answer (score 0):

The `proc` command creates a new command. The syntax for the `proc` command is

> **proc** *Name* *args* *body*

when `proc` is evaluated, it creates a new command with name *Name* that takes  arguments *args*. When the procedure *Name* is invoked, it then runs the script contained in the *body*.

The following is simple Tcl script using `proc` command to find sum of two values:

```
proc sum {arg1 arg2} {
    set x [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}];
    return $x
}

puts " The sum of 2 + 3 is: [sum 2 3]"
```

This is the input script.

The output:

```
The sum of 2 + 3 is 5
```

**Note:**  Here the new command is now `sum`.